# Align Arabic text in table to the right if there is a line break

Tags: html, html-table

How to align the second span text to the right? First span is already aligned but after the line break second span starts from the left

```
<td align="right">
  <span>${arabicLabels.DVD_NAV}</span> <br /> 
  <span>${arabicLabels.SCREEN}</span>
</td>
```

Output:

[image: arabic_text]

I want both of spans be aligned right. In the picture there is one TR and two TD, left side english and right side arabic. We care about the right TD which is mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the `direction` property

You can achieve this goal by setting the `direction` property to `rtl` (right to left).

```css
.right{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="left">
  <span>DVD_NAV</span> <br> 
  <span>SCREEN</span>
</td>
<td class="right">
  <span>ا..............العربیة</span><br>  
  <span>بسم اللہ</span>
</td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you are asking but flex is a great way to position elements

```css
#t1{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td id='t1'>
  <span>DVD_NAV</span>  
  <span>SCREEN</span>
</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  test
</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This completely breaks the `table`, stacking `td`s from the same `tr` on top of each other.

Comment: it does not break the table.  I'm stacking spans inside a td which is fine. But I like your solution as it's less code.

Comment: Add a `td` to your `tr`, never-mind you changed it up now

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the `text-align` style property to `right`.
However, Arabic is a rigtht-to-left language (I assume that's why you want it right-aligned) and should be styled accordingly with `direction: rtl;` which will automatically align things correctly.

```css
.arabic {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>DVD_NAV</span><br>
      <span>SCREEN</span>
    </td>
    <td class="arabic">
      <span>DVD_NAV</span><br>
      <span>SCREEN</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```